# object data url does not accept jquery commands

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have an url rotator.it have 2 divs , 1st div is menu, second is another website in object data(as in codes).
i try to close some ads on that urls in my site.i use jquery for this from chrome console but codes not working on my domain.

```
</div>
    <div id='1'>
<object name="main" data= 'http://<?php echo $url1 ?>' type="text/html">    </object>
    </div>



$(document).ready(function(){

   $("ul[object.name='main']").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#clickMe").on('click', function(e) {
    $("object[name='main']").remove();
    alert('object removed');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<div id='1'>
    <object name="main" data='http://www.apache.org/' type="text/html"></object>
</div>
<button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>
```

If there is no CORS violation you can use:

```
var p = $($("object[name='main']")[0].contentDocument.children[0]).find('p');
```

See [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: not selecting anything , infact at least ('ul') or ('p') i wan to select

Comment: it is ok i can select object but i need to select 'ul' or 'p' inside that.